# Add preset folders and files in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-set, subfolders

I'd like SharePoint to make a preset of folders and files when adding a new folder in a library.

Ex: WE have a library named 'Customers', where we have all our customers. 
When adding new folder (new customer) in that library, I'd like the folder to contain a subset of folders and files. 
Id also like to inherit folder rules if possible. 
Ex: The subfolder named 'contracts' will only be read and write for administration.
Another subfolder named 'lists' to be read and write for the whole company.

Is the question understandable? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Document Sets instead of folders in the root of the library. With a document set content type, you can set default content for the document set to contain when it is created. That should solve your first requirement.

For the permissions requirement, you can create a SharePoint Designer Workflow, and use the "List Item Permissions" actions to update the users who will have access to the Contracts folder inside the document set.

Hope this helps!